# What do exclamation '!' and period '.' mean in a switch config file

Tags: switch, network

what do the ! and . mean in switch config files?

```
Current configuration: 1363 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service pad
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch A
!
Command Purpose
Step 1 configure terminal Enter global configuration mode.
enable secret 5 $1$ej9.$DMUvAUnZOAmvmgqBEzIxE0
!
.
<output truncated>
.
interface gigabitethernet0/1
ip address 172.20.137.50 255.255.255.0
!
interface gigabitethernet0/2
mvr type source
<output truncated>
...!
interface VLAN1
 ip address 172.20.137.50 255.255.255.0
 no ip directed-broadcast
!
ip default-gateway 172.20.137.1 !
!
snmp-server community private RW
snmp-server community public RO
snmp-server community private@es0 RW
snmp-server community public@es0 RO
snmp-server chassis-id 0x12
!
end
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Network Engineering. In a Cisco environment `!` indicates a comment or command lines to be ignored. `.` is indications, that configuration has been truncated (removed) from the original config.

Comment: So in this example case that I posted ! has just been used  to make code more readable?  Coz nothing follows !. Thanks Cown.

Comment: Yes, in order to make the configurations more readable, Cisco made the `!` and added it between all the configuration sections to give it simplicity and make it more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Cisco environment, when utilizing `show running-config` and `show startup-config` the exclamation (`!`) points are only there to help in formatting the output to make it more readable and create space between sections in the config.

The period (`.`) is used to truncate (remove) long sections of config, that is identical.

They do not have any other meaning.

Answer (score -1):

hi is just googled myself here because in some cases these ! are absolute irritating ie. in this output where the grouped logic of "aaa authentication login telnet local
(and) username cisco password 0 Ocsic "  is ripped by that !. For my logic I dont group those lines without having a prior knowledge about the output:

```
aaa new-model
aaa authentication login default none
aaa authentication login telnet local
!
username cisco password 0 Ocsic
!
line vty 0
password LetMeIn
login authentication telnet
transport input telnet
line vty 1
password LetMeIn
transport input telnet
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.